# using snap.svg to move by increment using keyboard arrows

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

I am trying to move an svg called myCurser BY not TO a position.
the objective is to move shapes along a grid, in this case 40x40.
later the increment will be changed dynamicly.

I know i can **move to** and specify a new cx for the svg. but I cannot write
cx = cx + 40.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/yoavba/pen/doMrdp)

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var myCurser = s.circle(0, 0, 10);
//var myCurser2 = s.circle(40,40,2)

myCurser.attr({
    fill: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 1  
});

var increment = 40;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {

 switch(e.which) {

   case 37: // left

   break;

   case 38: // up
   break;

   case 39: // right

   myCurser.transform(t'40','40');

   break;

   case 40: // down
   break;

   default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
   }
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer I gave in an email...

You would want to do something like...

```
myCurser.attr('cx', +myCurser.attr('cx') + 10)
```

Note, the extra + in there, is to make sure it doesn't add a string, and it just adds the number.

You could also add a plugin to do something like that, it may be a bit confusing, but its useful if you have to repeat code. So the plugin would look something like...

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
   Element.prototype.increaseAttr = function(myattr, value) {
      return this.attr(myattr, +this.attr(myattr) + value);
   }
});


myCurser.increaseAttr('cx', -10) //// Move left
```

Here's a codepen with one method moving for right, and another for left.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGVNRJ)

You may want to look into transforms if you will be moving more complicated objects around.